# JavaScript : How to format the amount decimal to 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimalformat

I tried to format the Amount field to 2 digits using the
Amount.toLocaleString()
toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }),

[image: Screen Shot]

Some of the Amount values are displayed correctly but few are incorrect
like $52.85.00 should be displayed as $52.85

Comment: Show what you did to get that result

Comment: Does your amount have not more than 2 decimal places? like only $52.85 and $52 not like $52.8 or $60.275?

Answer (score 0):

```
function financial(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(financial(123.456));

console.log(financial(0.004));`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.prototype.toFixed()` to format with a number of decimals. Note: The toFixed method will return a string, so you should convert back to an floating number if your goal is not just to display. For more info on `.toFixed()` method [access document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
let numberToBeFormatted = 212.121212;
let formattedNumber = parseFloat(numberToBeFormatted.toFixed(2))
```